# Problematic clip already set on Canvas in onDraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, textview

I subclassed `TextView` to provide a custom onDraw. But canvas has a clip region applied that is nonsensical: the `x` is set to something well outside the view bounds. I *think* that's thwarting my purposes.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    // draw numberLabel
    if (numberLabel == 0)
        return
    val right = this.width - this.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.topNavBadgeEndMargin)
    // top needs to add the top margin and estimated text height
    val top = this.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.topNavBadgeTopMargin) + this.badgePaint.textSize
    canvas.drawText(numberLabel.toString(), right, top, this.badgePaint)
    val r = Rect()
    canvas.getClipBounds(r)
    Log.d("TopNav", "canvas.clipBounds: $r")
}
```

Logcat printed:

> D/TopNav: canvas.clipBounds: Rect(524187, 0 - 524389, 147)

FYI, I have also tried drawing a circle r=50 center=(100,100) and it doesn't show. So what would help is a) why this happens? b) I know there's no way to reset the clip region, but is there any workaround that would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like if you override `onDraw` in a `TextView` you need to offset by `scrollX` (probably should do `scrollY` as well, though it was zero). `scrollX` was the rediculously large int and I have no idea why it would be nonzero in a TextView that doesn't need to scroll.

```
    val right = this.scrollX + this.width - this.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.topNavBadgeEndMargin)
```

If you have several operations then `canvas.translate` wrapped by `save` and `restore` probably helps.